# Tidymodels dials: Error: Element `id` should have unique values. Duplicates exist for item(s): 'penalty', 'mixture

Tags: r, tidymodels

I faced this error ``` Error: Element ``id`` should have unique values. Duplicates exist for item(s): 'penalty', 'mixture" ``` when tuning a model with **tidymodels**. It took me a while to catch the cause of the error.
I'm posting it here in case some one faces the same error.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.1      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.9      ✓ rsample   0.0.8 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.2      ✓ tibble    3.0.3 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.2      ✓ tidyr     1.1.2 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.2.0 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.3      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

lr_spec <- 
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine(
    "glmnet",
    penalty = tune(),
    mixture = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

parameters(lr_spec)
#> Error: Element `id` should have unique values. Duplicates exist for item(s): 'penalty', 'mixture'
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is due to a silly mistake from my side in defining the `lr_spec`. I defined the tune parameters `mixture` & `penalty` inside `set_engine()`, whereas they should have been defined inside `linear_reg()`

```r
library(tidymodels)

lr_spec <- 
  linear_reg(
    penalty = tune(),
    mixture = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet") %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

parameters(lr_spec)
#> Collection of 2 parameters for tuning
#> 
#>  identifier    type    object
#>     penalty penalty nparam[+]
#>     mixture mixture nparam[+]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>